# Is there a way to "work around" the retention state of a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

What's going on?...

So, this is my case. I'm elaborating a web scrape, so that at some point of this script I have decided to make use of a decorator for handling some URLs. This decorator has an argument (the URL) in which should change dynamically with the help of a for loop statement, as the sample script shows:

```
from functools import wraps
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def cycle(url):
    def outer_wrapper(func):
        state = 0
        @wraps(func)
        def inner_wrapper(**kwargs):
            nonlocal state
            state += 1
            kwargs['url'] = url
            if state == 1:
                logging.info('Returning result at first execution on {} with: '
                             'state => {}, kwargs => {}'.format(func, state, kwargs))
                return func(**kwargs)
            else:
                logging.info('Returning result at upcoming executions on {} with: '
                             'state => {}, kwargs => {}'.format(func, state, kwargs))
                return func(**kwargs)

        return inner_wrapper
    return outer_wrapper


def print_url(url):
    print('Returned from print_url function:', url)

links = ['an-url', 'another-url']

for link in links:
    # Decorator
    print_url = cycle(link)(print_url)
    print_url()
```

However,  the output shows unexpected results, at least for me.

```
INFO:root:Returning result at first execution on <function print_url at 0x000002202FD68D08> with: state => 1, kwargs => {'url': 'an-url'}
Returned from print_url function: an-url
INFO:root:Returning result at first execution on <function print_url at 0x000002202FE196A8> with: state => 1, kwargs => {'url': 'another-url'}
INFO:root:Returning result at upcoming executions on <function print_url at 0x000002202FD68D08> with: state => 2, kwargs => {'url': 'an-url'}
Returned from print_url function: an-url
```

The decorator retains the addressing and argument of the first time at which the `print_url()` function is called.
I have read a lot of articles about garbage collection, weak references and standard library's `functools`, but I could not figure out how to "restart" this decorator with the purpose of it receives a new argument during the iteration process.

Would anyone have some cue how to solve this issue—if that is possible?

Comment: Because *you are re-decorating your already decorated function*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are re-decorating your already decorated function.

After the first iteration of:

```
for link in links:
    # Decorator
    print_url = cycle(link)(print_url)
    print_url()
```

Then `print_url` refers to `inner_wrapper`. You decorate `inner_wrapper` again. This has nothing to do with garbage collection, this is simply what you have written this to do.

This becomes more clear if you remove `wraps`:

```
def cycle(url):
    def outer_wrapper(func):
        state = 0
        def inner_wrapper(**kwargs):
            nonlocal state
            state += 1
            kwargs['url'] = url
            if state == 1:
                print('Returning result at first execution on {} with: '
                             'state => {}, kwargs => {}'.format(func, state, kwargs))
                return func(**kwargs)
            else:
                print('Returning result at upcoming executions on {} with: '
                             'state => {}, kwargs => {}'.format(func, state, kwargs))
                return func(**kwargs)

        return inner_wrapper
    return outer_wrapper


def print_url(url):
    print('Returned from print_url function:', url)

links = ['an-url', 'another-url']

for i, link in enumerate(links):
    print("Iteration :", i)
    print_url = cycle(link)(print_url)
    print_url()
```

And the terminal output:

```
Iteration : 0
Returning result at first execution on <function print_url at 0x1060892f0> with: state => 1, kwargs => {'url': 'an-url'}
Returned from print_url function: an-url
Iteration : 1
Returning result at first execution on <function cycle.<locals>.outer_wrapper.<locals>.inner_wrapper at 0x106089378> with: state => 1, kwargs => {'url': 'another-url'}
Returning result at upcoming executions on <function print_url at 0x1060892f0> with: state => 2, kwargs => {'url': 'an-url'}
Returned from print_url function: an-url
```

If you want access to the original function, I suggest just keeping a reference to it outside the loop and don't assign the result of the decorator to that variable, something like:

```
original_function = print_url
for link in links:
    # Decorator
    print_url = cycle(link)(original_function)
    print_url()
    print_url = original_function
```

just for fun, you *could* recover it on each iteration doing something to the effect of:

```
for link in links:
    # Decorator
    print_url = cycle(link)(print_url)
    print_url()
    closure = print_url.__closure__
    idx_func = print_url.__code__.co_freevars.index('func')
    print_url = closure[idx_func].cell_contents
```

But ... that's just a horrible mess that exposes a bunch of internal details that are better left under the hood.

Fundamentally, I am not sure why a decorator is required here, that is, what is the advantage of using this decorator?

Comment: Well, this was a pretty quick answer and indeed it solved my problem. Thanks! The purpose of the decorator is for syntax training. I want to get used to more complex approaches for coding. Your answer spotted me that I must study more decorators because I really didn't understand how this simple assignment prior the for loop solve my problem!

Comment: @Dg_gt again, once you decorate `some_func = decorator(some_func)`, then `some_func` refers to *whatever is returned by the decorator*. In this case, you return a wrapper function, which you keep decorating.